# How can I find out what Page has installed my Facebook App / which page is loading my app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a canvas app (http://apps.facebook.com/myapp) and other pages (businesses, etc) can Add it to their page. Within my app, how can I know which page I'm being called from?

I'm using the PHP-SDK

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As documented in [Facebook Page Tab Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/):

> When a user navigates to the Facebook
>   Page, they will see your Page Tab
>   added in the next available tab
>   position. Broadly, a Page Tab is
>   loaded in exactly the same way as a
>   Canvas Page. **When a user selects your
>   Page Tab, you will received the
>   `signed_request` parameter with one
>   additional parameter, `page`. This
>   parameter contains a JSON object with
>   an id (the page id of the current
>   page)**, admin (if the user is a admin
>   of the page), and liked (if the user
>   has liked the page). As with a Canvas
>   Page, you will not receive all the
>   user information accessible to your
>   app in the signed_request until the
>   user authorizes your app.

So one way to capture the page id would be:

```
<?php
// PATH TO FB-PHP-SDK
require '../../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
  'cookie' => true,
));
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
if( $page = $signed_request['page'] ) {
    echo $page['id'];
}
?>
```

OR a solution without the PHP-SDK:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_REQUEST["signed_request"])) {
    $app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
    $data = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST["signed_request"], $app_secret);

    if (isset($data["page"])) {
        echo $data["page"]["id"];
    } else {
        echo "Not in a page";
    }
}

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

    // decode the data
    $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

    if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
        error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
        return null;
    }

    // check sig
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        return null;
    }

    return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the part before defining two functions. I was totally lost looking at Facebook developers section until I saw your code. I wish Facebook API documentation team would realize how useless their way of documenting any features is.