# Facebook API - how to get page ID using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

With Facebook API, within a custom app added to a fanpage (tab app), how do I get the fanpage ID?

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

- user goes to the full-width canvas app, he authorizes himself there and allows the app to add a tab to one of the fanpages he's administrating
- every Facebook user going to that fanpage, sees the tab and the tab shows content specific to that fanpage (that's why I need to know the fanpage ID)
- if fanpage administrator wants to change something, he goes to the full-width canvas and logs in to my service (here's where I store what he wants to show in his Fanpage)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find out what Page has installed my Facebook Canvas App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587784/how-can-i-find-out-what-page-has-installed-my-facebook-canvas-app)

Comment: canvas app is different from the tab app. For example, in the tab app I don't have `signed_request`.

Comment: I'm not talking about the canvas app in the above answer. Here are my suggestions, 1) double check your app settings 2) make sure that you are not doing any redirection otherwise the signed_request will be lost! 3) check this [thread](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=91179)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a parsed signed request (to an tab iFrame) you can get the page id - the contents would be similar to the following (output of PHP print_r):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [issued_at] => xxxxxxxxxx
    [page] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => FAN_PAGE_ID // target page id
            [liked] => 1        // is the user a fan
            [admin] =>          // is the user an admin
        )

    [user] => stdClass Object
        (
            [country] => ie
            [locale] => en_GB
            [age] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [min] => 21
                )

        )

)
```

For more information see:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: the thing is that $_REQUEST in tab app does not contain `signed_request` (but in the canvas mode it does). How do I get it?

Comment: The `signed_request` parameter is only passed on the initial tab load. Are you sure there's no redirect occurring within the tab iFrame?